# Calculating a Net of Adds and Deletes in PowerPivot

Tags: powerpivot

I have data in a PowerPivot data model with two different date fields, one for the added date, and another for a removed date.  I would like to create a calculation that will allow me to summarize a net change by month.  Meaning I want to aggregate the count of the adds by month, the removes by month and the net change by month.

Enclosing an example of the data (A) and ultimately what I would like to aggregate (B).

Any direction would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Sample of data and desired result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two relationships between your fact table and your date dimension. One will have to be inactive. I'll assume an active relationship between Fact[Added] and DimDate[Date] and an inactive relationship between Fact[Removed] and DimDate[Date].

```
Adds:=
COUNTROWS( 'Fact' )

Removes:=
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS( 'Fact' )
    ,USERELATIONSHIP( 'Fact'[Removed], DimDate[Date] )
)

Net:=
[Adds] - [Removes]
```

Make sure that you use the date field from your date dimension in the pivot table, and not either of the date fields in your fact table.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you for the solution!  Works great